# Haskell writing my own function to compose functions

Tags: function, haskell

so I am trying to write my own function to compose a function n times in Haskell.

so for example, the input

```
compose (+1) 3
```

would return `f(x) = x+3`;

Now my attempt is as follows, but is actually quite naive and currently doesn't work.

```
compose f 0 = (*1)
compose f n = (compose f n-1).a
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second case, you are trying to refer to `a` which I think you meant as `f`, since then

```
compose f n = (compose f (n-1)) . f
```

(note also that `compose f n - 1` is parsed as `(compose f n) - 1` in your code)

which means you have

```
compose f 3 = (compose (+1) 2)             . f
            = ((compose (+1) 1)       . f) . f
            = (((compose (+1) 0) . f) . f) . f
            = ((((*1)            . f) . f) . f
```

Oh and by the way, you can write

```
compose f 0 = id
```

which expresses the idea that `compose f 0` should do "nothing".

Comment: Ok, so I was testing, and it seems the main issue I was having was brackets around 'n-1'. Do you perhaps have a reason why that screws up the function?

Comment: Yes, because then it gets parsed as `((compose f n) - 1)` i.e. it's trying to subtract 1 from `compose f n` which is not a number.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. That actually clarified a bunch.